# combining multiple sets into a single one and remove duplicate ones

Tags: java

I have m sets, which can be stored using array, or arraylist. There are overlaps among these sets. I would like to combine these m sets into a single set, and those duplicate elements will only occupy one spot in the combined set. Which kind of data structure and operation should I use to construct the combined set.

Comment: A [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do it for you:

```
    Set set = new HashSet();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList(); //etc
    Object[] array = new Object[]{};
    Object[] array2 = new Object[]{}; // etc
    set.addAll(list);
    set.addAll(list2);
    set.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
    set.addAll(Arrays.asList(array2));
    // Call addAll as many times as you like
```

`set` now contains all unique values once each

Answer (score 4):

See: javadoc of java.util.Set.**addAll**(Collection):

```
/**
 * Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this set if
 * they're not already present (optional operation).  If the specified
 * collection is also a set, the <tt>addAll</tt> operation effectively
 * modifies this set so that its value is the <i>union</i> of the two
 * sets.  The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified
 * collection is modified while the operation is in progress.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * Join multiple sets into one.
 */
@SafeVarargs
private final <T> Set<T> join(Set<T>... sets)
{
    Set<T> result = new HashSet<>();
    if (sets == null)
        return result;

    for (Set<T> set : sets)
    {
        if (set != null)
            result.addAll(set);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store them in a `java.util.Set` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) has a ListOrderedSet. It combines the advantages of the Set (namely, each element occuring only once), with those of a list (iteration in the order of addition).

With it, do what the others suggested:

- Construct a new ListOrderedSet lOS.
- Add all your elements into it using lOS.addAll(yourElements).

Answer (score 0):

From **Java 8**, you can use a **stream** to combine multiple set into one

```
Set<Long> ALL_IN_ONE = Stream.of(SET1, SET2).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```